# How to overdrop a video with black backgroud in the video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency

everything is in the title ;).
How to make blender use black as alpha?

Answer (score 2):

To perform a Luma key in the VSE you need to use the Strip modifiers.

However you want to use the source or foreground strip as a key or Mask, and Blender doesn't like making loops (as you are modifying the source with the source which becomes modified etc.).

So you need to duplicate the strip then turn it of with the H key (hide strip). This becomes the Key source strip. You could then Group this pair so that they stay in sync if you move them or trim them on the timeline. In my example I have not done that just so you can see the steps required.

[image: Luma key in VSE]

You can better define the value to key by adding a curve modifier to the Key source strip, and make it more contrasty (steeper curve).

[image: Define edge]

For best results you will have to reduce the color of the original strip to make an accurate key. Use the Key source's Saturation slider, reduced to 0.0

[image: Refine Key]

For more control you could add a blur effect to the Key source strip then Hide it Alt-H and define the Blur strip as the mask on the foreground strip modifier.

[image: Blur key]

You can also use a curve modifier on the Key source strip to invert the key.

Again I strongly recommend grouping all of these strips together and muting the ones that are used as keys, this saves them accidentally appearing in the composite.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender that's not difficult.  Not sure about Cycles though.  To begin with it might be cleaner to produce an alpha layered video with the black areas converted to transparency.  This can then be used as a video in the VSE to overlay other images/video(s)

The transparency video would be a series of single frame .png files.  Create a special folder for that - there'll be a lot of them.

This image sequence is treated like any other video file in the VSE.  The images can be zipped up into a file for archiving and future use.

The process -

At the top of the Blender window expand where it says "Default" and open up the Compositor window.

Once there, add the following nodes (with SH-A) and connect up as shown, however use an Input Node-->Movie instead of the image node I've used.  Enter your own movie file location at the bottom of that node.

xxxxx[image]

In the "Keying" node you'll notice that I've set the "Erode" value to -1.  It trims back a slight black border I ended up with at the top right of the cube.

Set the key color to just a little lighter than the black areas in your film or image.  You'll notice that I deliberately used dark grey behind the cube in the image and set the key colour a tad lighter than that.  (there's no reason you can't use black outright)

-=====-

To render it out as .png alpha, go into the properties panels at extreme right, select the camera icon (at it's left) for the render settings.

In the "Output" tab at bottom set your special folder location and also set the format in the left slot to "PNG".

Now go to the right and set it to alpha. Click on "RGBA".

In the "Post Processing" tab higher up make sure the Compositor box is ticked.

You're all set to go!  Click on the Render button at the top.

Once done add the finished image sequence as a strip into the VSE and play it or just look at a single frame.  You should see a chequered pattern where previously there was a black area.

This is how mine looked in 'Gimp'.  The cube was "Photographed" as an ordinary black background image. (that was what was used by the Input node in the compositor)

[image]

Before mixing this or overlaying with other footage, change the render output settings back to a video format and new folder.  Also make sure the VSE box is ticked in the "Post Processing" panel.

Back in the VSE, select the transparent strip and press 'N", set the 
strip's property (at top) to "Alpha Over".

Add your other footage underneath that strip.

I see you've used the term 'Noob', so add any queries as a comment here and I'll edit the answer...